# Rally App SDK 2.0: Filtering the store for a rallymultiobjectpicker

Tags: javascript, extjs, rally

I am attempting to use a rallymultiobjectpicker (not sure why there isn't a single object picker) to pull up a list of portfolio items. However, I would like to filter the results by the "Portfolio Item Type" field. I have not had luck with the recognition of the revised storeCfg's parameters. Any modifications seem to be ignored, even something as simple as changing the sorting on the "Name" field from "ASC" to "DESC".

Here is a basic example:

```
this.pis = Ext.widget('rallymultiobjectpicker', {
    items: [{
        modelType: 'portfolio item'
    }],
    storeCfg: {
        autoLoad: false,
        fetch: "Name, PortfolioItemType",
        pageSize: 200,
        filters: [
            {
                property: 'PortfolioItemType',
                value: 'Initiative'
            }
        ],
        sorters: [
            {
                property: 'Name',
                direction: 'DESC'
            }
        ],
        remoteGroup: false,
        remoteSort: false,
        remoteFilter: false,
        limit: Infinity
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I will try to address your questions as you wrote them.

The single object version of the multi-object-picker is the [combobox](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.ComboBox). As a side note for selection any Portfolio Item of a type I would probably use the [Chooser](https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/doc/#!/api/Rally.ui.dialog.ChooserDialog) component. Pickers and combobox components work well unless there are too many options in them. The chooser is a great way to allow your user to find exactly the object that they are looking for without giving them a list a million long to look through.

Also PortfolioItemType is an object not just a string value. But you can query by it's name which is shown below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/apps/2.0p/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {

                Ext.create('Rally.ui.dialog.ChooserDialog', {
                    artifactTypes: ['portfolioitem'],
                    autoShow: true,
                    listeners: {
                        artifactChosen: function(selectedRecord) {
                            Ext.Msg.alert('Chooser', selectedRecord.get('Name') + ' was chosen');
                        },
                        scope: this
                    },
                    storeConfig : {
                        filters: [
                            {

                                property: 'PortfolioItemType.Name',
                                value: 'Initiative'
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Tacos'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is a multi object picker

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<script type="text/javascript" src="https://rally1.rallydev.com/apps/2.0p/sdk.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    Rally.onReady(function() {
        Ext.define('CustomApp', {
            extend: 'Rally.app.App',
            componentCls: 'app',

            launch: function() {
                this.add({
                    xtype: 'rallymultiobjectpicker',
                    modelType: 'portfolioitem',
                    storeConfig : {
                        filters: [
                            {

                                property: 'PortfolioItemType.Name',
                                value: 'Initiative'
                            }
                        ]
                    },
                    listeners:{
                        collapse:function(picker){
                            console.log(picker.getValue());
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });

        Rally.launchApp('CustomApp', {
            name: 'Tacos'
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Ah, yes. I should have made that assumption about the combobox's relationship to the multiobjectpicker. I have tried your example, and it seems to work, except that it is populated with what seems to be ALL the Portfolio Items with Type "Initiative" in the Workspace, rather than just the selected Project.

Also, is there any way you could provide an example of a working multiobjectpicker, just so it is available as an answer to the original question, as well as an option?

Comment: Usually I like making sure that you get all the options in the chooser since it has it's own filtering capabilities. When I have a few I will create a multiobjectpicker example that solves this as well. Oftentimes Portfolio Items are in a very different part of the project hierarchy.

Comment: Hey, Charles, I was hoping you didn't forget about this and could find some time to put something together. Thanks.

Comment: Hey. I just got to trying this out. The filtering doesn't quite work. The rallymultiobjectpicker doesn't seem to have a "storeConfig". I have also tried modifying it to "storeCfg" to no avail.